# How does the first star in this program get printed?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Im trying to figure out how the first star in this program gets printed. When the loop that controls the stars is first encountered the value of stars should be 1 due to the initialization withing the loop, the value of light should be zero because it was assigned zero in the declaration of light. The condition to print out the first star is (stars < light) which means ( 1 < 0 ) well thats false right? But the program prints out a star anyways! Whats going on?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int empty = 10; // stars intial value
int light = 0;  // space inital value
int lines;      // number of lines on screen
int stars;      // number of stars each iteration
int spaces;     // number of spaces each iteration

for(lines = 0; lines <= 10; lines++)          // number of lines
{
    for(spaces = empty; spaces > 0; spaces--) // number of spaces
    {
        cout << " ";
    }

    for(stars = 1;  stars < light; stars++)    // number of stars
    {
        cout << "*";
    }

    cout << endl;

    light += 2;
    empty--;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger? Doing so should shed some light on this..

Comment: I bet it happens on the second loop through the outtermost for loop.

Comment: But the `light` variable is uninitailized before the loop begins, so there is a possibility that `light` could randomly be set to a number like 15.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure I follow that logic. It looks like it's declared as `int light = 0; // space initial value`

Comment: @glowcoder:  The OP has edited the post.  In the post I was referring to, the `light` variable was not initialized, but used in the `for` loop.

Comment: @Thomas doesn't appear to be edited. It was edited at 20:40, while your comment was an hour later. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing it on the second iteration.

When light is equal to 2, it will print 1 star.

Answer (score 3):

On the second iteration of this loop:

```
for(lines = 0; lines <= 10; lines++)          // number of lines
```

The `light` variable will be 2, because of this line in the loop which adds two to `light`'s current value:

```
light += 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Second time through the loop it prints the star.

The key is:
light += 2;

I think you're thinking it's printing it the first time through, but it's not.

Comment: Ahh yes I see now its the second time through now. The first time it just prints out 10 spaces, but the second time it prints out that first star. Now I get why there are 10 lines of stars and not 11 lines of stars. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

On the second iteration of the primary outer for-loop, the value of light will be `2` since it's incremented at the end of the first primary out for-loop iteration ... therefore, since `stars` is initialized to a value of `1` each time it enters it's own inner for-loop, it will be less than `2`, and thus you will be able to print-out the star characters.  Also on each successive cycle of the loop, `stars` will be less than the value of `light` at that point, and will keep printing star-characters.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the loop runs, it won't print any stars but increment the value of light by 2. By the second iteration you'll have stars < light, and you'll have your first star printed

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your output when running - When I run the above I get an initial std::cout and then the first star of the pyramid.